Как код влияет на скорость компиляции?
Всё зависит от общего количества кода, количества зависимостей или сложности кода и использования сложных функций и т.д.?
Например что быстрее скомпилируется:

куча if
один switch


Разница между конкретными инструкциями внутри файлов с кодом примерно одинакового размера скорее всего будет незаметна. Тут скорее важен общий размер файла с кодом и количество этих файлов, если их много. Потом ещё линковаться всё это между собой может тоже заметное время, если там много зависимостей. Да и то на современных компьютерах с SSD диском и современным многоядерным процессором, вы разницу заметите только на очень больших проектах, мне кажется.

А с чего такой вопрос? Писать код исходя не из эффективности работы, а эффективности компиляции - несколько странный шаг, нет?

@Harry вопрос резонный. Встречал обсуждение аналогичного вопроса в Java сфере. там вышло что switch/case выполняются медленнее чем конструкции с if. Автора видимо волнует код в котором в цикле будет множественное обращение в такому коду.

@Rootware Вы говорите о скорости работы готового кода?

@Rootware Автор вопроса спрашивает о скорости компиляции, а не о скорости выполнения кода. Хотя может быть он нечётко сформулировал.

Исследуйте и расскажите нам. :) Я бы не парился - тормозить будут многоэтажные шаблоны, а не вот это вот.

Скорость компиляции или скорость результирующего кода?

Не формальный ответ (так и не пойму, зачем это надо...), но вот что дает Visual C++ 2022 на моей машине для такого странного кода
int n;
cin >> n;
switch(n)
{
case 0 : cout << "0\n"; break;
case 1 : cout << "1\n"; break;
case 2 : cout << "2\n"; break;
case 3 : cout << "3\n"; break;
case 4 : cout << "4\n"; break;

(и так 64000 раз) время компиляции + линковки по 10 запускам компилятора с оптимизацией — 22±2с, без оной 17.7±0.7с.
Те же 64000 раз в виде
int n;
cin >> n;

if (n == 0) { cout << "1\n"; }
if (n == 1) { cout << "1\n"; }
if (n == 2) { cout << "2\n"; }
if (n == 3) { cout << "3\n"; }
if (n == 4) { cout << "4\n"; }
if (n == 5) { cout << "5\n"; }
if (n == 6) { cout << "6\n"; }

(else не пустил, говорит, переполнение внутренностей компилятора :))
с оптимизацией 17.0±0.9с, без оной 14,7±0.3с
Выводы делайте сами.
Размер exe'шника почти одинаков, 2.5 Мб независимо от оптимизации.

А если в обратном порядке: сначала второй код таймить, а потом первый, ничего не меняется? А вдруг там что-то у компилятора кэшируется при первом запуске компиляции. )

@CrazyElf Я среднее по 3 запускам подряд вычислял. OK, сейчас для 10 перезапущу и отклонения укажу...

else не пустил - вроде 256 уровней макс вложенность может быть. Compiler Limits - похоже, здесь надо смотреть

@AlexanderPetrov В стандарте есть только ограничения снизу (когда-то был такой вопрос на ruSO, кстати).
